# Arc fuction c++

Tags: c++, windows, geometry, visual-studio-2019, imgui

Hi i am trying to make a quarter circle in dear imgui for this i need a arc fuction

```
void ImDrawList::PathArcTo(const ImVec2& centre, float radius, float a_min, float a_max, int num_segments)
{
    if (radius == 0.0f)
    {
        _Path.push_back(centre);
        return;
    }
    _Path.reserve(_Path.Size + (num_segments + 1));
    for (int i = 0; i <= num_segments; i++)
    {
        const float a = a_min + ((float)i / (float)num_segments) * (a_max - a_min);
        _Path.push_back(ImVec2(centre.x + ImCos(a) * radius, centre.y + ImSin(a) * radius));
    }
}
```

issue is this does this http://prntscr.com/rsyaaf i want it too do this http://prntscr.com/rsybsj how do i solve this
the code above is from dear imgui

Answer (score 0):

Add  `_Path.push_back(centre);` in all cases to provide right angle centered in arc center instead of chord